Text-to-Speech (TTS) не правильно ставит ударения в русских словах
Проблеме Text-to-Speech (TTS) не правильно ставит ударения в русских словах около 10 лет (+-). Но никто это не может исправить эти ошибки до сих пор!/?
Я разбиваю слова на слоги. Иногда это помогает. Но так работать нельзя!
Ошибок в ударениях очень много!
Например, врет ударение в слове: нападать. Произносит: напАдать, разбил слово на два слога: напа дать, немного помогло.
Слово: господа произносит как: гОспода, разбил на: госпо да. Немного помогло.
Никак не могу поправить ударение в слове кровоточить
(прозносит как: кровоточИть)
Но это все не решения! Это убогие костыли. Кто-нибудь решил задачу?

Есть библиотека ruAccent, но помимо этого надо использовать синтезатор речи который может понимать ударения
